# Can I update SPF using an MX record instead of TXT because I can not edit TXT records during propagation?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am in the process of moving DNS (not the domain registration though, that's staying with GoDaddy) from GoDaddy to Bluehost for a client. I transferred the DNS two days ago but I can not access the cPanel Advanced DNS Editor (in Bluehost) to update the TXT record to recognize the email provided through GoDaddy - essentially, my client's email is in limbo until everything propagates properly with Bluehost. They say this can take 7 days.

In the meantime, I set up his email on Bluehost so he can still send/receive using their email system, but ideally, he can go back to using O365 through GoDaddy sooner than later. I was expecting at the very least for the access to the cPanel DNS editor to work as soon as the website switched over, which was immediately.

Is there a way to update TXT records outside of cPanel while propagation is in limbo or can I add an MX record to solve some of this?

According to GoDaddy, this is the code I need to add to a TXT record, which I can't access anywhere:

```
v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all
```

The domain in question is `wedgerx.com`.

Comment: They probably have "7 days" in the script because of the old NS records in the parent zone being cached, for which a TTL of 1 week used to be not uncommon – however, if the website has already switched over, then that's definitely no longer an issue. That only leaves "propagation" in their internal systems, which ought to be instant because it's their own systems, so it smells like their support staff has no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

> “…my client's email is in limbo until everything propagates properly with Bluehost. They say this can take 7 days.”

Really? The DNS management was being handle by GoDaddy but now is handled by Bluehost and they are claiming an (up to) 7 day email buffer period?

That sounds incompetent.

It could be that Bluehost is so used to people setting their DNS TLL to 1 week (604800) that they just set up their system to delay access to TXT records for 1 week. I would definitely contact Bluehost directly and see if they can clear things up. There is no way to do an “end run” around cPanel or whatever interface they allow users to use to change DNS records.

You should be able to add a TXT record at any time and the only delay is actually in the propagation. I would contact Bluehost directly and ask them about it. The “7 days” seems like an artificial delay at best.